# How to Test Ethernet Based Modbus FreeRTOS TCP/IP Client Software on STM32 with Host PC without a Router?

Tags: tcp, stm32, ethernet, freertos

I have legacy software including FreeRTOS TCP IP stack, it is a client and wants to connect 192.168.1.100 server address with **FreeRTOS_connect** API function.
I thought the following steps would work if I do peer-to-peer ethernet connection in a way one end is my STM32 device and other hand is my Host PC ethernet port then, I'd set my host PC IP to 192.168.1.100 statically and then run Modbus Slave software as server and listen port 502.

However, my ethernet icon on my PC says "network cable unplugged", and my RTOS API function returns connection timeout. I know am looking at the software from a quite high-level point but I need to be sure whether a router is required and if are there any missing steps here.

Comment: It sounds like maybe your ports don't support auto MDI-X, in which case you'd need to use a crossover cable. Or just get a cheap Ethernet switch that does support auto MDI-X, and plug both your devices into that. You don't need a router.

Comment: @pmacfarlane xPhyDiscover API function returns 0 as the number of available port counts. I also ordered a cross cable to test.